# Can you add comments to a "jaxb.index" file?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

Has anybody found any documentation on comments in jaxb.index files? I've searched the web, but couldn't find any information.

Using "# comment" style lines does work, but is this actually specified anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format is specified in the [API documentation for the JAXBContext class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html).

"The comment character is '#' (0x23); on each line all characters following the first comment character are ignored."